# post media wordpress api in flutter

Tags: wordpress, flutter, wordpress-rest-api

hi guys I want to **send photo** from gallery phone to wordpress media with API but I cant upload image by API to Wordpress

```
how can I do this?
```

in bottom I send photo for my postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoHQF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZbvw.png)

Comment: please add some code that you have done yet

Comment: Please update your question with debugging details. We can't help you if there's no code.

Comment: i want just know what is media api wordpress in postman, now i dont know what is api form make code